# Exponential progress reporting

Tags: c#

I would like to report to an user the current progress about a background counter, however, I'm stuck in my method. 
Indeed, I want more the counter timeout is higher and more there will be information.

For example, if the user sets a counter with a timeout of 60 secs, the counter will display at 30secs the remaining time, but if the user sets a counter with a one day timeout, the counter will display approximately every hour the remaining time.

So I did this, but I think it could largely be optimized with an exponential way..
Could you help me please
Here's my code:

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds - i);
string strTime;

if (Seconds > 30 && Seconds <= 300)
{
    if (i == Seconds / 2)
    {
        strTime = time.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        account.Logger.LogMessage(LanguageManager.Translate("165"), LanguageManager.Translate("614", strTime));
    }
}
else if (Seconds > 300 && Seconds <= 1800)
{
    int firstOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds / 3));
    int secondOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds * (2/3)));

    if (i == firstOcc || i == secondOcc || i == Seconds - 60)
    {
        strTime = time.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        account.Logger.LogMessage(LanguageManager.Translate("165"), LanguageManager.Translate("614", strTime));
    }
}
else if (Seconds > 1800 && Seconds <= 7200)
{
    int firstOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds / 5));
    int secondOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds * (2 / 5)));
    int thirdOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds * (3 / 5)));
    int fourthOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds * (4 / 5)));

    if (i == firstOcc || i == secondOcc || i == thirdOcc || i == fourthOcc || i == Seconds - 60)
    {
        strTime = time.ToString(@"H\:mm\:ss");
        account.Logger.LogMessage(LanguageManager.Translate("165"), LanguageManager.Translate("614", strTime));
    }
}
else if (Seconds > 7200 && Seconds <= 43200)
{
    int firstOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds / 8));
    int secondOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds * (2 / 8)));
    int thirdOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds * (3 / 8)));
    int fourthOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds * (4 / 8)));
    int fifthOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds * (5 / 8)));
    int sixthOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds * (6 / 8)));
    int seventhOcc = System.Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)Seconds * (7 / 8)));

    if (i == firstOcc || i == secondOcc || i == thirdOcc || i == fourthOcc || i == fifthOcc || i == sixthOcc || i == seventhOcc || i == Seconds - 60)
    {
        strTime = time.ToString(@"H\:mm\:ss");
        account.Logger.LogMessage(LanguageManager.Translate("165"), LanguageManager.Translate("614", strTime));
    }
}
else if (Seconds > 43200)
{
```

Which is very redundant

Comment: The backgroundwork report has two overloads 1) int 2) int, state object.  I would use the 2nd overload.  See my solution in a recent posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553764/port-scanner-slow-and-freezing-ui-in-c-sharp-net-2-0/59582222#59582222

Comment: So this code runs at most once a second, takes a fraction of a microsecond to execute.  You can't optimize 0.0001% of processor load and ever notice any improvement.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it seems like OP is referring to optimizing in terms of repetition.

Comment: Yes, I would like to optimize repetition ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the log base 2.  So the timers would be 32 seconds, 64 seconds, 128 seconds, 256 seconds, 512 seconds, 1024 seconds, 2048 seconds.  So code would look something like this :

```
            List<int> seconds = new List<int>() { 60, 200, 400, 600, 800, 2300, 3599 };

            foreach (int second in seconds)
            {
                int timer = (second < 64)? 32 : (int)Math.Pow(2,(int)Math.Log(second, 2));
                Console.WriteLine("Seconds : '{0}'; Timer : '{1}'", second, timer);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks this way is cleaner and more efficient than mine lol Thx !

Answer (score 1):

Here is an (untested) example of how you might go about refactoring your code to prevent repetition.

```
var time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds - i);

if (seconds <= 30)
{
    // What to do here?
    return;
}

int factor;
string format;

if (seconds <= 300)
{
    factor = 2;
    format = @"mm\:ss";
}
else if (seconds <= 1800)
{
    factor = 3;
    format = @"mm\:ss";
}
else if (seconds <= 7200)
{
    factor = 5;
    format = @"H\:mm\:ss";
}
else if (seconds <= 43200)
{
    factor = 8;
    format = @"H\:mm\:ss";
}
else
{
    // Defaults when no other condition is met.
    factor = 10;
    format = @"H\:mm\:ss";
}

if (i == seconds - 60 || Enumerable.Range(1, factor - 1).Any(n => i == seconds / factor * n))
{
    string timeDisplay = time.ToString(format);
    account.Logger.LogMessage(LanguageManager.Translate("165"), LanguageManager.Translate("614", timeDisplay));
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! That was the way i was looking for ! Nice =)